# Read SQL Values with reflection and assign the correct datatype

Tags: sql, types, reflection, changetype

Until now i got SQL-results from a datareader and stored it in a collection, all variables were strings:

```
                AdressEntries client = new AdressEntries();
                Type t = client.GetType();
                            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {

                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    client = new AdressEntries();
                                    foreach (PropertyInfo variable in t.GetProperties())
                                    {
                                        variable.SetValue(client, reader[variable.Name].ToString());
                                    }
                                    allClients.Add(client);
                                }
                                reader.Close();
```

this worked great for all kind of collections. Now i want to use more datatypes in the app and in the SQL Database (like date, int, double etc.) The variables used in the collections are nullable (like int?, Boolean?, etc.).

Now i have to cast/convert the SQL-Results. I did this with a little correction to the above code with Convert.ChangeType:

```
 using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {

                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    client = new AdressEntries();
                                    foreach (PropertyInfo variable in t.GetProperties())
                                    {
                                        variable.SetValue(client, Convert.ChangeType(reader[variable.Name], variable.GetType()));
                                    }
                                    allClients.Add(client);
                                }
                                reader.Close();
```

Can I do this, or do I run into problems?

Comment: Not sure what is the setup here? Is your reader returning string or any data type?

Comment: Without knowing specifics. Would be useful to know, what is the driver here? A property info property type or Reader column type?

Scenario 1 - reader returns string, but you want to set value of any data type.
scenario 2 - reader returns specific type. 
You need to clear this up

Comment: The reader returns different types. For example an Adress with Guid, strings, birthdate, integer Numbers and so on. I read the result into an object with the exact same datatypes. If i get a date from the database, i store it in a DateTime variable. But i have to cast it, right?

Comment: Then in this case your problem is solved. All you need is `object val = reader["x"] == DBNull.Value ? null : reader["x"];  variable.SetValue(client, val);`

Comment: I don't understand. I have to Cast/Convert the reader results in one way or another, or not? How do I implement your solution in my reflection-line above correctly?

Comment: If you can guarantee that your reader returns same datatype as your property than you don't need to convert. If your column is `int` your reader can return `DBNull.Value` or `int`. the `int` value is boxed in `object`. `SetValue`  also expects `object`. No need for casting or anything. Only if you have `DBNull.Value`, if your property is `int?`, only then you need to convert `DBNull.Value` to `null`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this works great. I don't even use Nullable Variables anymore. So i can keep the "old" reflection from my first method and remove the toString(). The only thing i wonder now, why does an empty (NULL) integer which i get from the Database convert to 0 in C#?

Comment: int x = null is not allowed in C# wpf Version 7.3, or do i miss something?

Comment: Actually, you're correct. This is in VB you can do this... But if you do `Convert.ToInt32(i)` then you get `0`